# How to solve this nonlinear inhomogeneous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this nonlinear inhomogeneous differential equation?
$$
a\dfrac{d^{2}x(t)}{dt^{2}}-b\left(\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}\right)^{2}=c
$$
Where a, b, c are constants.

Comment: If $u = \frac{dx}{dt}$ then $\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ODE is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}t} = B\,u^2 + C
\end{equation}
with $ \ B=b/a$, $\ C=c/a \ $ and $\ u=\text{d}x\,/\,\text{d}t$.

On separation of variables and integration
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}u}{B\,u^2+C} &= \text{d}t ,\\
\frac{\arctan\left(u \sqrt{B/C} \right)}{\sqrt{BC}} &= t - t_0 ,\\
u(t) &= \frac{\tan\left( \sqrt{BC}(t-t_0)\right)}{\sqrt{B/C}}.
\end{align}
Now integrate once more to obtain
\begin{equation}
x(t) = -\frac{\log\Bigl( \cos\bigl(\sqrt{BC} (t-t_0) \bigr) \Bigr)}{B} + K_0,
\end{equation}
where $t_0$ and $K_0$ are determined by the initial conditions.